# Is there a way to use functions to auto-populate outer context with variables in php?

Tags: php, function, variables, scope

I was wondering... Let's consider this:

```
function get_current_post_id(){
  global $wp_query;
  return $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
}
```

Later...

```
function test($post_id = null){
   if(!$post_id) $post_id = get_current_post_id();
}
```

Ok. But it would be fantastic if I could only write this:

```
function test($post_id = null){
   if(!$post_id) get_current_post_id();

   // ...and directly have $post_id populated and ready to use
   do_something($post_id);
}
```

And have my $post_id variable auto-populated in the current context (the test() function). Is there a way? I mean, **without using globals**.

Comment: If you don't want to use globals, you'd have to edit `function get_current_post_id() {...}` to receive parameters, and pass `$wp_query` as a parameter. Also, in `function test() {...}`, since `get_current_post_id()` returns a value, you'd have to assign it to a variable to use it, let's say `if(!$post_id) { $post_id = get_current_post_id($wp_query) };`

Comment: This obviously contradicts with the idea behind scoping of identifiers... You could use a reference parameter, but then you can also assign a return value. For multiple values you can use php's `list()` function. But you always have to do that in an explicit manner. Which definitely does make sense from a robustness point of view: the inner function has no knowledge of the outer scope, therefore would risk breaking things...

Comment: @Condorcho: no, that's not my question

Comment: @arkascha yes, makes sense.

Comment: @arkascha I added the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found that's possible, as @arkascha said, I can pass by reference:

```
function get_current_post_id(&$post_id = null){// &$post_id instead of $post_id
  global $wp_query;
  $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
  return $post_id; // optional
}
```

The thing is: I can simply pass the variable by reference.
Then:

```
function test($post_id = null){
   if(!$post_id) get_current_post_id($post_id); // even if I know it's null

   // ...then $post_id will be auto-populated
   do_something($post_id);
}
```

Comment: Sure, that is just what I mentioned. However it reduces the readability of the code which _always_ is a bad idea.

Comment: Not in this case, since it's my own self-closed ;) functions library. Thank you.

Comment: You will quite certainly curse yourself for this in the future, believe me.

Comment: I'll remember you told me. ;)

Comment: Remember - you are always writing code for someone else to read. Even if that someone else is you in 2 weeks time ;-)